# In matlab, how to generate 1:n in a matrix form without using loop ? e.g. when n=6, I want [1 2;3 4;5 6] instead of [1 2 3 4 5 6]

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, how to generate numbers 1:n in a 2x(n/2) matrix form without using loop ? e.g.when `n=6`, I want `[1 2;3 4;5 6]` instead of `[1 2 3 4 5 6]`.

Comment: See: [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `reshape` function:

```
n = 10;
reshape(1:n,2,[])'

ans =

     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
     7     8
     9    10
```